# What's the best practice for handling mostly static data I want to use in all of my environments with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, admin

Let's say for example I'm managing a Rails application that has static content that's relevant in all of my environments but I still want to be able to modify if needed. Examples: states, questions for a quiz, wine varietals, etc. There's relations between your user content and these static data and I want to be able to modify it live if need be, so it has to be stored in the database.

I've always managed that with migrations, in order to keep my team and all of my environments in sync.

I've had people tell me dogmatically that migrations should only be for structural changes to the database. I see the point.

My counterargument is that this mostly "static" data is essential for the app to function and if I don't keep it up to date automatically (everyone's already trained to run migrations), someone's going to have failures and search around for what the problem is, before they figure out that a new mandatory field has been added to a table and that they need to import something. So I just do it in the migration. This also makes deployments much simpler and safer.

The way I've concretely been doing it is to keep my test fixture files up to date with the good data (which has the side effect of letting me write more realistic tests) and re-importing it whenever necessary. I do it with `connection.execute "some SQL"` rather than with the models, because I've found that `Model.reset_column_information` + a bunch of `Model.create` sometimes worked if everyone immediately updated, but would eventually explode in my face when I pushed to prod let's say a few weeks later, because I'd have newer validations on the model that would conflict with the 2 week old migration.

Anyway, I think this YAML + SQL process works explodes a little less, but I also find it pretty kludgey. I was wondering how people manage that kind of data. Is there other tricks available right in Rails? Are there gems to help manage static data?

Answer (score 0):

In an app I work with, we use a concept we call "DictionaryTerms" that work as look up values. Every term has a category that it belongs to. In our case, it's demographic terms (hence the data in the screenshot), and include terms having to do with gender, race, and location (e.g. State), among others.

[image]

You can then use the typical CRUD actions to add/remove/edit dictionary terms. If you need to migrate terms between environments, you could write a rake task to export/import the data from one database to another via a CSV file.

If you don't want to have to import/export, then you might want to host that data separate from the app itself, accessible via something like a JSON request, and have your app pull the terms from that request. That seems like a lot of extra work if your case is a simple one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm looking for is the approach used by other people on how they manage the modifications to this data over time.

The import / export idea doesn't work for me because it doesn't solve my problem of having the process be seamless for my whole team and for deployments. It's something else you have to remember to do during deployments and remind coworkers as well.

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for better ways to manage these "data migrations", ideally using the migration mechanism.

Comment: You could write a migration, but that's a static, one-time import. That's easy enough, and if that's all you need, you can go that route. If instead it was a rake task (even of statically imported data) you would want to make it part of your Capistrano deploy tasks, or whatever deployment tool you use for deployment. Including it in your automated deploy tasks removes the burden of people having to remember to do it, since it's automatic.

Comment: Hmmm, I like the idea of a simple rake task. Easy for any coworker to grok, and easy to automate on deployments. Why didn't I think of that? :-)